# RDS Postgres oldest replication lag increases during inactivity even though Fivetran connector keeps synchronizing

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, postgresql-13

I'm in the process of setting-up a datawarehouse using Fivetran as the ETL layer. One of the source databases is a AWS RDS Postgres instance.

I've configured the Postgres instance to perform Logical Replication of the WAL using the test_decoding plugin. All seems to work fine during office hours, however outside office hours when no queries are preformed, the oldest replication slot lag size is increasing despite the fact the Fivetran connector performs a sync.

You can see this in the picture below. In the red box you the replication slot lag size is increasing (top graph) while the synchronization moments keeps happing every hour (bottom graph). I would expect a graph like shown in the green box, were the replication slot lag size is decreasing around the synchronization moments.

[image: replication_log_size_staging_vs_fivetran_log]

I contacted Fivetran with this issue, but they were yet unable to find out the problem, therefore I'm asking the community.

I'm using Postgres version 13.3 with the following custom configuration:

- `max_slot_wal_keep_size`: `20000`
- `rds.logical_replication`: `1`
- `wal_sender_timeout`: `0` (required by Fivetran)

The rest of the configuration is default.

I also checked other questions, there's only one that might come close https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103806/235086, but I'm unsure if it applies here since it about the lag in seconds instead of size.

Comment: What is the Y axis on your chart?

Comment: It's the size of the replication log lag in MB, so at the peak it's about 9GB.

Comment: I think your lag is also in time, not size.  If it was size, it would take time for it work through once it started again, but instead it just plummets instantly.  Also, if the system is idle, where is the size coming from?

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe that 9GB is entirely composed of log traffic which is not relevant to the part of the data you are replicating?  But still, what is generating it if the system is idle?

Comment: I have the same question, it's very counter-intuitive that the size is increasing while no queries are performed e.g. I don't expect a WAL when there are no queries.

Comment: There's also a graph with the transaction logs disk usage, it's increasing just like the oldest replication log size is increasing. So that also gives me the indicator that it's not just the lag time.

Comment: Could be the result of vacuuming I guess.  With RDS, I don't know how you can tell.  Otherwise, I'd recommend inspecting some of the new WAL files with pg_waldump to see what was in them.

Comment: Good suggestion, thank you! I could try to do a manual vaccuum outside the office hours and see if that results in a similair graph.

Comment: Just checked, a vacuum increases the replication slot lag. However if I inspect the restart_lsn and confirmed_flush_lsn of pg_replication_slots they're are both the same, indicating that the replication is not lagging. Same with sent_lsn and write_lsn of pg_stat_replication, both the same. Makes me wonder what the AWS RDS oldest replication lag graph shows.

Comment: The hypothesis about the log traffic might also be true. I created s single record in the database and performed a sync manually, that caused the replication lag size to plummet down like what you see in the green box on the graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem, it's due to the inactivity on the database. Since there are no changes in the database outside office hours there are no changes to be consumed by the replica e.g. the Fivetran connector, therefore the LSN of the WAL is not advancing and the replication lag increases.

It seems that others had the same problem and came up with a solution called a **'WAL heartbeat'** see [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html), [2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216253/postgres-9-4-wal-level-logical-increases-disk-space), [3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229469/heartbeat-frequency-in-aws-dms-database-migration-service), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589058/aws-rds-postgresql-transaction-logs-keep-going-when-there-is-no-data-change) and [5](https://wolfman.dev/posts/pg-logical-heartbeats/). This is a recurring proces e.g. cron job that writes a tiny amount of dummy data in the database to advance the replication slot.

Fivetran later confirmed that they've also seen this behaviour and are therefore rolling out WAL heartbeat support in Q3 2021.

Because there was no built-in WAL heartbeat support in RDS or from Fivetran (yet). I've implemented my own, by creating a recurring background job that creates a record every 15th minute e.g. 13:15, 13:30, 13:45. This solved the problem, as you can see the graph below. After the deploying the fix I could see the expected sharkteeth over the weekend when there's normally no activity.

[image: replication_log_size_fixed]

*Debug information*

I also want to share how I was able to debug it.

I stayed awake during the evening to see what's going on when the replication lag increases. The moment that the inactivity starts I could see the replication lag increasing. So this confirmed the hypothesis about the inactivity.

When I inspected the `restart_lsn` and `confirmed_flush_lsn` of `pg_replication_slots` they're were both the same, indicating that the replication was not lagging.

Also when the connector was performing its sync, the slot became active and I could see that the `sent_lsn` and `write_lsn` of `pg_stat_replication` were both the same, also indicating that the replication was not lagging.

However in the replication lag graph was still increasing, eventhough the `pg_replication_slots` and the `pg_stat_replication` didn't indicate a lag.

In order to debug the issue even further I decided to create a record to get some activity going on the database, after creating a record I synced the connector manually. That's when I saw that the replication lag plummeted down. See the graph below.

[image: replication_log_size_drops_after_new_record_and_sync]

Based on these observations I'm concluded that the replication lag is increasing because there are no changes to sync, causing the database to keep it's WAL.