# Increasing TransactionLogsDiskUsage in postgresql 11.12 RDS instance

Tags: postgresql, replication, write-ahead-logging

We have a test RDS postgresql 11.12 instance, configured for logical replication. The only thing connected to it is a 3rd party service, Hevo Data, which is managing sync to a separate Redshift instance. There is no incoming data - inserts, updates, deletes etc

Hevo does an historical load - a bunch of `SELECT`s basically, initially. This has finished; all data is present in the destination Redshift instance.

However, the problem is that the metric `TransactionLogsDiskUsage` continues to steadily rise. This would make sense if there was incoming data/new transactions and a replication subscriber wasn't fetching transaction logs, but I don't think either of those conditions are true.

What could be causing this metric to go up?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [RDS Postgres oldest replication lag increases during inactivity even though Fivetran connector keeps synchronizing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/296289/rds-postgres-oldest-replication-lag-increases-during-inactivity-even-though-five)

Due to a lack of writes at the source, there's nothing to sync and (for whatever reason) postgresql retains write ahead logs in this case - until there is something to sync.

Doing an `INSERT` at the source caused `TransactionLogsDiskUsage` to drop to normal levels a few minutes later.